# Windows Server 2003 Notification on Failed Login

Tags: windows-server-2003, security

I would like to receive an email any time a failed login attempt occurs on our Windows 2003 server.  What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to post the entire script again, but [my answer here](https://serverfault.com/questions/47953/windows-event-log-email-notification/48391#48391) contains a script that will do what you're looking for. If you're looking for domain logon failures you'll need to install it on every domain controller since user logons can be processed by any DC.

I agree w/ mrdenny on this one, though. You could get a lot of email coming in quickly. That script has no rate-limiting capability in it (hey-- it's free), so be careful with it if you use it in production because an attacker could create a *slew* of email for you very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You would to audit all those failures, then setup a monitoring application to read the security log and trigger on that alert message.

Depending on the size of your company you could end up with a LOT of email coming in very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

We simply created a VBScript to poll the event log, place all bad logins for the last 15 minutes into an array, removed duplicates whilst maintaining a duplicate count, and then email that list out.  We then scheduled the script to run every 15 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just like to add that it's not the failed logons you need to worry about.  A failed logon is just a sign that your security is working; no concerns (although certain patterns of multiple failed logons are an indicator that someone or something is trying to brute force you).