# Windows: Audit/View logins from remote networks?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-event-log, security, intrusion-detection

i want to audit remote connection attempts to a Windows 2003 Server. i've changed the group policy to show logon successes and failures:

```
>gpedit.msc

Local Computer Policy
   Computer Configuration
      Windows Settings
         Security Settings
            Local Policies
               Audit Policy
                  Audit logon events: Success, Failure
```

And now the logs are filled with *failure* events like:

```
Logon Failure:
    Reason:                 Unknown user name or bad password
    User Name:              server
    ...
    Logon Type:             10
    Logon Process:          User32  
    Authentication Package: Negotiate
    ...
    Source Network Address: 82.114.195.29
```

While **Logon Failure** events sure are interesting, i'm *more* interested in **Logon Success** events - i want to see if anyone got in. That means it's not all **Logon Success** events i wants, just ones from foreign networks.

i want to filter the Windows Security Event log to show:

- Event type == "Failure audit"
- "Source Network Address" is from the internet

> Or for the more programmer oriented:
>
> ```
> (EventType == FAILURE_AUDIT) &&
> (SourceNetworkAddress & 0xffffff00) != 0x0a000000
> ```

Possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event viewer won't allow you to filter on criteria in the "Description" field, which is what you need to differentiate between "local" networks and "foreign" networks.

My [sshd_block](https://serverfault.com/questions/43360/cygwin-sshd-autoblock-failed-logins/43900#43900) script could be altered to do what you're looking for, or you could probably cobble something together using the [event log email notification script](https://serverfault.com/questions/47953/windows-event-log-email-notification/48391#48391) I wrote for an answer on Server Fault. Either one, however, doesn't have rate limiting on the notifications (which I really should get around to writing in my "copious free time"...)

Comment: Accepted for "Event viewer won't allow you".