# Event viewer filtering - MS Sql server - How to filter logins from outside?

Tags: sql-server-2008, eventviewer

I want to filter event log to show SQL logon that was initiated from other machines, I have thousands of logins from local machine and few ones from other machines. I want to monitor that connections from other machines. Only difference in that two events is in text.

**Local connection :**

```
Login succeeded for user 'tel_writer'. 
Connection made using SQL Server authentication. 
[CLIENT: <local machine>]
```

**Other machine connection:**

```
Login succeeded for user 'sa'. 
Connection made using SQL Server authentication. 
[CLIENT: 242.xxx.xxx.xxx]
```

Is there a any way to filer out this local machine connections ?

Comment: This is similar to an question i had, regarding logins to the computer itself (http://serverfault.com/questions/157187/windows-audit-view-logins-from-remote-networks)